# Compare > and >= efficiency

Tags: java, boolean

For a boolean expression, is ">" and "<" more efficient than ">=" and "<="? As the latter expressions need to test 2 conditions at the same time "=" and "<" or "=" and ">"?

Comment: These variations are available as one opcode even on machine level. There are seperate Zero and Sign flags, so `>= 0` might be done a bit more clever sometimes. Only division traditionally is slower than multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

No there's no difference in efficiency for most machines. Modern CPU instruction sets include native testing of 'and equal to' in exactly the same number of clock cycles. The JVM will convert the comparison to the correct instruction and performance will be equivalent.

For example, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings 'jump if' instructions for Intel chips. You can also see http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf for information on latency and throughput for each instruction. You will see that Jcc all perform the same.

To confirm this, I ran the following code:

```
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long t = 0;
    for (long i = 0; i < 1E10; i++)
            t++;
    long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (long i = 1; i <= 1E10; i++)
            t++;
    System.out.println((t2 - t1) + " / " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t2));
```

The result was 12701 / 12731. So no significant difference in performance.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt that there is any performance difference between these operators.

The Java Bytecode instruction set has separate operators for less-than and less-than-or-equal-to, named `iflt` and `ifle`, respectively. It has similar operators for greater-than comparisons (`ifgt` and `ifge`). Ultimately, it's up to the implementation of the JVM to determine how these bytecodes are interpreted at a lower level, but I feel it's a safe assumption that these operations happen in constant time since pretty much all physical architectures out there today provide this functionality in constant time.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same in terms of `O(n)` (efficiency), asking `if(a > b || a == b)` is the same as `if(a >= b)`. The only difference is that the computer reads some character more but in code efficient `O(n+n)` it **doesn't really change anything**. 
What matters is when you have something like `O(n^n)` and etc...

Comment: Complexity theory is great at analysing the theoretical efficiency of two competing algorithms. It doesn't help much in tuning the performance of actual code used to implement an algorithm. To do that you need profile code on real physical hardware.